# files transferring and renaming using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I made this script for extracting all json reports from nested folders"folders inside folders" the name of the root folder is"All_stock_report" and needed to extract json files (that have the name stock.json) to one only folder which is (All_stock_Json)

but the problem is that all the json files are all the same name(stock.json) which cannot be exported to one folder due to name conflict so I made this script which "supposed" to get each json file , rename it and then put it in (All_stock_Json). However when I run the code I get an error and I dont know how to solve it

```
from pathlib import Path

src = Path(r"\Users\Ray\Desktop\All_stock_report")
dst = Path(r'\Users\Ray\Desktop\All_stock_Json')

for fileNumber, file in enumerate(src.rglob("stock.json"), 1): 
    file.rename(dst / f"stock{fileNumber:0>2}.json")
```

The error I get

```
  File "Extract_Rename.py", line 7
    file.rename(dst / f"stock{fileNumber:0>2}.json")
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: How old is your Python?  f-strings came in with Python 3.6.  Try `file.rename(dst / "stock{0:0>2}.json".format(fileNumber))`.

Comment: You can check python version with `import sys;print(sys.version)`. The code doesn't have a syntax error when I run it on python 3.9.5,

Comment: Solved , thank you guys . turned out python version was the problem